# Activities dual monitor issue with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, gnome-shell, application-switcher, activities-overview

I found the Activities overview very useful in Ubuntu 18.04. Unfortunately, when I plugged the second display, I found out that it is impossible to switch between activities located at different displays using <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> (or <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow Keys</kbd>). Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: It is not a solution but an alternative that I found more or less appropriate: [Coverflow Alt-Tab extention](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/97/coverflow-alt-tab/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with [Coverflow Alt-Tab extention](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/97/coverflow-alt-tab/) for a while I think it is exactly a solution to my question!

You may find the usage instructions [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/97/coverflow-alt-tab/).